# How to publish Google apps script add-on with Picker API?

Tags: google-apps-script

I started to learn the Google Picker API and read the [File-open dialogs in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) guide.
I tested the sample code and it worked fine,
but I don't understand whether I can publish the Google apps script add-on including this feature.
My concern is that there is my 'DEVELOPER_KEY' on the code.
I don't know how to get 'DEVELOPER_KEY' for publishing, please help.

**EDIT**: My question is as follows: 
Is it the correct way to write down my Browser Key on my script, especially for publishing it as an Google Apps Script add-on?

Isn't it dangerous to publish my Browser Key value? Can add-on users see my code.gs and/or page.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish the add-on with the picker.  I have publish add-ons using picker myself(private to my domain or else I would share them with you).
To find your key, from the editor open the resources menu and select Developers Console Project.  Click the link to open the project your script is currently associated with.
Now from the developers console project, assuming you have already enabled the picker api, open the credentials menu.  If you have already created a browser key it will be listed here.  If you havent, click Create new Key under Public Api Access, then select Browser Key.
The referers you need to add in the text box are:
*.google.com
*.googleusercontent.com
Once you have entered these click Create.
You developer key will be listed as the API key  for this browser application key.  To use it in your code, simply assign the value to the DEVELOPER_KEY variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jonathan. But I know how to get the Browser Key. I apologize for any confusion. My question is as follows: Isn't it dangerous to publish my Browser Key value? Can add-on users see my code.gs and/or page.html?

Comment: There is no risk.  You api key does not grant access to any account information, and is not used for authorization.  It is simply a key to identify your unique application to the picker api.  
Also users do not have access to your code.gs, or the html used to generate the picker dialog.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear that. Thank you for everything, Jonathan. I'm really grateful for your help.